# Issues while inputting strings in C

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, fgets

I am trying to write a C program that takes `n` as an integer input and then inputs `n` strings. The problem that when I run the program, it takes one input less than `n`. If I enter `1` as the first input the program just terminates. Here is the code :

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char str[101];

while (n--) {
    fgets(str, 101, stdin);
    // other stuff...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Your program will work if you use `scanf()` for the number *and* the string input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[101];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n--)
    {
        scanf("%s", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it's arguably better to use `fgets()` for all the inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[101];
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(str, "%d", &n);
    while (n--)
    {
        fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I scarcely need to remind you since you used `fgets()` in the first place, you'll be aware that it retains the `newline` at the end of the input string.

Comment: Note: Better to use `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);` 1) is should be 101 not 100 and 2) avoid magic numbers.  +1 for "better to use fgets() for all the inputs."

Answer (score 1):

Remember that hitting the enter key sends a character to the stream too. Your program fails to account for this. Use the format `scanf(%d%*c)` to discard the second character.

```
int main(void) {

    int n;

    scanf("%d%*c", &n);

    char str[101];

    while (n--)
    {
        fgets(str, 101, stdin);

        // other stuff.....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char str[101];

while (n--) 
{
fgets(str, 101, stdin);
// other stuff...
}
```

In this as you enter `n` and press `ENTER` from keyboard `'\n` is stored in `stdin` therefore as `fgets` encounters `newline character` if returns .

Therefore use this after `scanf`-

```
 char c ;
while((c=getchar())!=NULL && c!='\n');
```